# Clusterization with mask

Tags: image-processing, opencv, mask, k-means

Actually I have already asked this question in [official Q&A](http://answers.opencv.org/question/3111/clusterization-in-opencv/) but didn't get any answer yet.

My task is to use [kmeans clusterization](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/core_clustering.html) not for the whole image but only for it's masked part. So as input I have two images:

1. Masked image.
2. Image converted to Lab color space.

And if I clusterize image on **n** clusters, after clusterization with mask I want to have image with **n+1** clusters (+1 because of mask).

Of course I researched and googled it but found nothing.

Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create another image, copy the data unmasked data in it, and use this matrix to perform your kmeans. This is how it goes:

[edit]

The following does not work, it only black-out pixels in the mask, but tmp has same dimension as original image.
    cv::Mat tmp;
    labImage.copyTo(tmp, mask);

You should allocate the tmp matrix beforehand, and fill it with a loop over the mask:

```
cv::Mat tmp = cv::Mat::zeros(cv::countNonZero(mask), 1, labImage.type());
int counter = 0;
for (int r = 0; r < mask.rows; ++r)
  for (int c = 0; c < mask.cols; ++c) 
    if (!mask.at<unsigned char>(r, c))
      // I assume Lab pixels are stored as a vector of floats
      tmp.at<cv::Vec3f>(counter++, 0) = labImage.at<cv::Vec3b>(r, c);
```

[/edit]

```
cv::kmeans(tmp, k, labels);

// Now to compute your image of labels
cv::Mat labelsImage = cv::Mat(labImage.size(), CV_32S, k); // initialize pixel values to K, which is the index of your N+1 cluster

// Now loop through your pixel mask and set the correspondance in your labelImage
int counter = 0;
for (int r = 0; r < mask.rows; ++r)
  for (int c = 0; c < mask.cols; ++c) 
    if (!mask.at<unsigned char>(r, c))
      labelsImage.at<int>(r, c) = labels.at<int>(counter++, 0);
```

Comment: What is the second line? which method you try to call?

Comment: Sorry, but your solution is wrong for me - `copyTo` with mask just makes unmasked pixels black, but I don't want to clusterize these pixels at all (read my question again). But anyway thanks for your help (+1).

Comment: I was sure it would work but I tested the code and indeed, copyTo just blacks out the masked pixels. Then, you should create your own data matrix with as many rows as the number of non-masked pixels (use [`countNonZero`](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html?highlight=countnonzero#cv.CountNonZero) for that), and use the same loop as in my answer to fill the tmp matrix before kmeans

Comment: On a side note, k-means would perform much faster if you clusterize the histogram instead of the full pixel data. Moreover, [calcHist](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/histograms.html?highlight=histogram#CvHistogram*%20cvCreateHist%28int%20dims,%20int*%20sizes,%20int%20type,%20float**%20ranges,%20int%20uniform%29) supports a mask! But OpenCV k-means implementation does not support clustering histogram (a weight must be added to each data). The [C clustering library](http://bonsai.hgc.jp/~mdehoon/software/cluster/) does!

Comment: Thanks for suggestion but it seems that such algorithm is very slow (iteration + check in cycle) so I'm looking for faster way of solving the problem.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18373/discussion-between-remi-and-astor)

Comment: Thanks to your answer - see your edited function [in my own answer here](http://answers.opencv.org/question/3111/clusterization-in-opencv/?answer=3384#post-id-3384).

Comment: Did you get the answer to your [first question there](http://answers.opencv.org/question/3111/clusterization-in-opencv/?answer=3384#post-id-3384) ? That would be `cv::Mat mask = (labelImage == k)`, where k is the ID of the cluster you want to mask out.